# How can I get the CurrentSite object in Orchard?

Tags: c#, orchardcms, outputcache

What I'm trying to do, ultimately, is access the `CacheSettingsPart` so that I can programmatically add some ignored URLs to the output caching config.

The relevant admin controller already achieves this with:

```
   var settings = Services.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<CacheSettingsPart>();
   settings.IgnoredUrls = model.IgnoredUrls;
```

I need something similar for my own method, but when I try and inject `IOrchardServices`, the `WorkContext` is `null`, meaning I don't have access to the `CurrentSite`.

I need suggestions of achieving this with an alternative approach or, ideally, a way of accessing the `CurrentSite`/`CacheSettingsPart` for me to amend the `IgnoredUrls`.

### **EDIT**

```
var query = Services.ContentManager.Query<CacheSettingsPart>();
var cacheSettingsPart = query.List().First();
```

The above seems to be giving me what I need, I'll now test whether amending `IgnoredUrls` persists or not.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a controller or scheduled task?

Comment: @DavidCornish Apologies, should've explained this. It's called as part of a migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WorkContext, as far as I can see, hasn't been created at the point of the Migration being run.

You could get the first SettingsPart as you suggest - it's probably not used for anything except the current site, though if you had multiple tenants, then I think you might run into trouble.

An alternative would be to inject `ISiteService` into your migrations class.

You can then do

```
var site = _siteService.GetSiteSettings();
var cacheSettings = site.As<CacheSettingsPart>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var query = Services.ContentManager.Query<CacheSettingsPart>();
  var cacheSettingsParts = query.Slice(1);

  if(cacheSettingsParts.Any())
  {
     _signals.Trigger(CacheSettingsPart.CacheKey);
     cacheSettingsParts.First().IgnoredUrls = "/dans-test";
  }
```

The above works, but I appreciate it might not be the best approach so I'm open to other suggestions.